# Percentages of values in rows grouped by Chargepoint

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHVZA.png)

Does somebody know how I can answer to the question: Which socket_id is used more (socket id 1 or socket id 2) per Chargepoint_skey? And show that in percentages, so that I can see fast for a particular chargepoint for example: in 60% of the cases socket 1 is used and in 40% of the cases socket 2 is used at chargepoint x.

My code so far to get the dataframe:

```
vraag_6 <- FACT_CHARGESSESION_JOINDIMLOCATION %>%
           select(ChargePoint_skey, ChargeSession_skey, Socket_ID) %>%
           group_by(ChargePoint_skey)

subset_vraag_6 <- subset(vraag_6, !Socket_ID == "XXXXXX") %>%
                  group_by(ChargePoint_skey)
```

Comment: Can you share reproducible example using dput() ?

Comment: The dataframe has 101578 rows, so I don't know how can easily share that with you, if that's what you mean? Dput output was too big to post it here ... :(

Comment: you can do dput(head(df,10)) where df is your dataframe

Comment: structure(list(ChargePoint_skey = c(3669, 3704, 3704, 3588, 3148, 
2352), ChargeSession_skey = c(9501222, 14374723, 14204382, 9326489, 
10112787, 17682592), Socket_ID = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("ChargePoint_skey", "ChargeSession_skey", 
"Socket_ID"), groups = structure(list(ChargePoint_skey = c(2352, 
3148, 3588, 3669, 3704), .rows = list(6L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2:3)), .Names = c("ChargePoint_skey", 
".rows"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

Comment: @KarthikS I used head(mydata, 6) because with 10 it was still too long

Comment: Daniel, have given my answer, I changed your data a bit, changed 4th row, as there weren't many varieties in groups in the data you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ChargePoint_skey, Socket_ID) %>% 
     mutate(freq = n()) %>% 
       group_by(ChargePoint_skey) %>% 
                mutate(Most_Sockets = freq/n())
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   ChargePoint_skey [4]
  ChargePoint_skey ChargeSession_skey Socket_ID  freq Most_Sockets
             <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>     <int>        <dbl>
1             3669            9501222 1             1        1    
2             3704           14374723 1             2        0.667
3             3704           14204382 1             2        0.667
4             3704            9326489 2             1        0.333
5             3148           10112787 2             1        1    
6             2352           17682592 2             1        1
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   ChargePoint_skey [4]
  ChargePoint_skey ChargeSession_skey Socket_ID
             <dbl>              <dbl> <chr>    
1             3669            9501222 1        
2             3704           14374723 1        
3             3704           14204382 1        
4             3704            9326489 2        
5             3148           10112787 2        
6             2352           17682592 2
```

Comment: Can you can give me a good description of the column freq? Of what exactly is it the frequention?

Comment: @daniel, so first am grouping by those two columns and finding counts. Then I am just grouping by skey column to get percentages

Comment: This was the code where I was looking for:

subset_vraag_6_2 <- subset(vraag_6, !Socket_ID == "XXXXXX") %>%
                    count(ChargePoint_skey, Socket_ID) %>%
                    group_by(ChargePoint_skey) %>%
                    mutate(perc_n = n/sum(n))

I first needed to delete the socket id's with the value XXXXXX. 

Thanks for your time and effort though!